# How to add event to system set in bevy

Tags: rust, bevy

i want to add event like this:

```
    pub fn add_system_set_event<T>(&mut self) -> &mut Self
where
    T: Component,
{
    self.insert_resource(Events::<T>::default())
        .add_system_set_to_stage(CoreStage::First, SystemSet::new()
            .with_run_criteria(FixedTimestep::step(2.0))
            .with_system(Events::<T>::update_system.system()))
}
```

because i want reuse the event system cache logic.

i known timer system can do "fixed time" logic, but it is not cache.

I’m not sure if this example is a new requirement, or any other way can do this in bevy